# Understanding of matrix XOR product

Tags: matrix-calculus, quantum-computation

I'm new to the topics of quantum computing in the theory of computation. However, I'm quite lost trying to understanding the mechanism of how to XOR 2 simple matrices.

$A \oplus B$ given 
$A = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
           1 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$
and 
$B = \begin{bmatrix}
           1 \\
           0 \\
    \end{bmatrix}$

to get the result of 
$A \oplus B$ = $\begin{bmatrix}
                0 \\
                1 \\
                0 \\
                0 \\    
                \end{bmatrix}$
Although I am attempting on figuring out myself, I am quite running out of time. Therefore, I really look for the responsive explanation from you guys. I have tried looking up those things online, but I haven't got any relevant sources worth explaining its fundamental.

Thanks,

Comment: It's not an XOR, it's a tensor product ($A \otimes B$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not an XOR, it's a tensor product, also called the [Kronecker Product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). Think of copying the second vector, and multiplying it against the first vector:

$A \otimes B = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \cdot B \\
           1 \cdot B\\
    \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
           0 \\
0\\
           1 \\
0
    \end{bmatrix}$

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate it, and the mechanism is actually straightforward. I indeed misswapped the value of matrix A for B. Sorry!